# neither inArray or indexof finding values in an array of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function () {
    var arDates = [ new Date("2014-03-15").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-03-19").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-03-21").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-03-24").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-03-26").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-03-28").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-03-31").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-03").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-06").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-08").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-15").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-22").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-24").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-27").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-04-30").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-05-03").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-05-06").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-05-08").valueOf(),
    new Date("2014-05-15").valueOf(),
]
    $('.date').pickmeup({
        date        : new Date(1397084400000),
        flat        : true,
        format      : 'Y-m-d',
        calendars   : 3,
        render: function(date) {
            if ($.inArray(date.valueOf(), arDates) != -1)
            {
                return {
                    class_name: 'cal_log_date'                         
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

I'm trying to create a function which checks if a date is in an array and if it is it does something. But it doesn't seem to work for any dates after 2014-03-30 and I have no idea why?

Heres an example of the code running: http://jsfiddle.net/L2aq4ph2/

Comment: *"Does seem to work..."* Does or Doesn't?

Comment: You seem to have hard-coded a value `new Date(1397084400000).valueOf()` that *does not* exist in the array

Comment: @GeorgeJempty the new Date(1397084400000).valueOf() is just to start the user selected date on the calendar

Comment: @TimLewis sorry my bad doesn't work

Comment: @renlok I figured as much :P

Answer (score 1):

your problem is Daylight Saving:

`Sun Mar 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

`Mon Mar 31 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)`

You have to use [UTC times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) all the way...

```
$(function () {
var arDates = [ 
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 15),
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 19),
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 21),
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 24),
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 26),
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 28),
    Date.UTC(2014, 3-1, 31),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 03),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 06),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 08),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 15),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 22),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 24),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 27),
    Date.UTC(2014, 4-1, 30),
    Date.UTC(2014, 5-1, 03),
    Date.UTC(2014, 5-1, 06),
    Date.UTC(2014, 5-1, 08),
    Date.UTC(2014, 5-1, 15)
]
$('.date').pickmeup({
    date        : new Date(1397084400000),
    flat        : true,
    format      : 'Y-m-d',
    calendars   : 3,
    render: function(date) {

        var y = date.getUTCFullYear();
        var m = date.getUTCMonth();
        var d = date.getUTCDate();

        var evaluateDate = Date.UTC(y, m, d);

        if ($.inArray(evaluateDate, arDates) != -1)
        {
            return {
                class_name: 'cal_log_date'                         
            }
        }
    }
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/apedroso/L2aq4ph2/5/)

Comment: Good job -- can you update the fiddle for future seekers?  (I was also working on this problem and would like to see your solution)

Comment: I've tried with `date.getTimezoneOffset()` and still don't get any results